# mySQL bigint to Matlab str

Tags: mysql, matlab, mysql-workbench, bigint

I am using Matlab to plot Aircraft Trajectories using a mySQL database to pull flight info. The issue is that Matlab will not read or store the mySQL **query** for the altitude data. The altitude data is stored in mySQL as a bigint(20), other data stored as doubles in mySQL are stored easily in Matlab via queries. I thought it was an issue when I tried to convert the numeric data to string but Matlab can't even get the data. I get the following error:

*Undefined function 'padarray' for input arguments of type
'int8'.
Error in edu.stanford.covert.db.MySQLDatabase/query (line 240)
                                absByteArray =
                                padarray(absByteArray, 8 -
                                numel(absByteArray), 0,
                                'pre')';
Error in WritetoKML6 (line 115)
conflictAlt1 = db.query();*

Comment: This looks like a problem with the "edu.stanford..." package you are using to access the mysql database.  It's going to be difficult for us to help, unless someone on SO has access to that package.  As a start, try running `dbstop if error` in Matlab and re-run the command.  This may break into the debugger at the point of the error and give you more information.

Comment: Can you just call `double(...)` on what is probably `java.math.BigDecimal` or `java.math.BigInt` typed data (use `class(...)` to find out your type)? Assuming the values fit with a double you should be fine.